# how to cut an object array to get specific attributes in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array like this

```
array = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Apple',
  color: 'red
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Orange',
  color: 'orange'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Banana',
  color:'yellow'
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: 'Malta',
  color:'orange'
}
];
```

and I just want to get "id" attribute from this array like this

```
 array = [
{
  id: 1,
},
{
  id: 2,
},
{
  id: 3,
},
{
  id: 4,
}
];
```

What should be the method to handle this situation.
I tried filter method , map method but it didn't work

Comment: Show what you have tried, `map` should do the job just fine here.

Comment: For non-destructive way, `map` is the correct way. However, please show your code; note that "it didn't work" is a useless description (if it worked, you probably wouldn't be here, asking), and a good description of _how, precisely_ it failed to work (with example input, example output and how it differs from the desired output) is much, much more useful.

Comment: You should be able to use `map` like `array.map(x => x.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` on the array:

```js
var initial = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Apple',
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Orange',
    color: 'orange'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Banana',
    color: 'yellow'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Malta',
    color: 'orange'
  }
];

var finalArray = initial.map(item => {
  return {
    id: item.id
  }
});

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `map` operator to iterate over the array like this -

```
array.map(res => {return {id: res.id}})
```

PS - or Another shortcut way as @amadan suggested in comment

```
array.map(({id}) => ({id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get the id property,

```
 arrayData.map(a => {
  return {
    id: a.id
  }
 })
```

```js
var arrayData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Apple',
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Orange',
    color: 'orange'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Banana',
    color: 'yellow'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Malta',
    color: 'orange'
  }
];

const newarray = arrayData.map(a => {
  return {
    id: a.id
  }
})
console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: This funny syntax also works nicely: `arrayData.map(({id}) => ({id}))`

Comment: @Amadan yeah I know :D